# How to avoid flickering when a MDI child form is shown in C# Windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net

When connected to RDC , Iam observing flickering issues for the background images of mdi child forms. How can I avoid them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Put this in the constructor after the InitializeComponent.

Comment: How about this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx You would lock the window, do the things you do and then unlock it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very late answer, but since all answers here (including the accepted) did not do anything against the flickering, I still like to post what did it for me

first of all, I had to do this

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;

        // reduce flickering when switching mdi child forms (see also WndProc)
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED (which is essentially double buffered)

        return cp;
    }
}
```

But this is not enough, I also had to do this :

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
{
    const int WM_NCPAINT = 0x85;
    const int WM_SIZE = 0x05;

    // reduce flickering when switching mdi child forms (see also CreateParams)
    if (msg.Msg == WM_NCPAINT)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            return;
    }

    // reduce flickering when switching mdi child forms (see also CreateParams)
    if (msg.Msg == WM_SIZE)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            return;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref msg);
}
```

I had read somewhere that I could achive all this by simply doing this :

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

But the flickering only gets worse when I do that.

Anyway, with this solution (at least in my mdi project) I have completely eliminated the flickering when switching between mdi child forms.
Hope this can help anyone looking for this problem.

Comment: Not working tested on Windows 10. This works but the title bar icons disapear.. at least for me. Perfect for me is to only add the first proposed funcstion (CreateParams) this avoid flickering and shows the title bar ok, but, when minimize and then maximize window it stop working

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code, no flicker at all.

```
if (!CheckForm(childForm))
        {
            childForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; //avoid flickering
            childForm.Show();
            childForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            childForm.BringToFront();
            childForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            childForm.Activate();
            childForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been also struggling with same problem and didn't find anything what works including form.DoubleBuffered = true. So this is what works for me

```
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
form.Show();
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

On the designer side, leave the form window state to Normal.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue for a long time. And I just got this way to come out. Opening forms in Fill Dock mode instead of Maximized.

```
//childFrm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
childFrm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Remove any background image in MDI form.